# simultaneous equation, solve for x & y

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'm stuck solving what appears to be a simple simultaneous equation. A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Solve the simultaneous equations for x and y:

$y=x^{2}+7x-11$,

$y=x-1$

my workings:
$0=x^{2}+6x-10$

$10=x^{2}+6x$

$10/x=x+6$

From here i go around in circles trying to solve for $x$. I'm sure i've missed something basic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know $y=x-1$ and you also know that $y=x^2+7x-11$.  Both of these are equal to $y$, so set them equal to eachother.  $x-1=x^2+7x-11$.  Can you continue?  The "quadratic formula" seems to be useful here.

Comment: Now i have 2 solutions for x=-3±√19. I understand the parabola but how do i use this to solve for y? There would only be one solution for y wouldn't there?

Comment: remember that $y=x-1$ so if $x=-3\pm \sqrt{19}$ then $y=-3\pm\sqrt{19}-1$.  When $x=-3\color{red}{+}\sqrt{19}$ then $y=-3\color{red}{+}\sqrt{19}-1$.  On the other hand when $x=-3\color{blue}{-}\sqrt{19}$ then $y=-3\color{blue}{-}\sqrt{19}-1$.  You get solution pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have
$x^2+6x-10=0$,
you have a standard quadratic equation.

Solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two equations
$$
\begin{align}
 y_{1}(x) &= x^{2} + 7x - 11 \\
 y_{2}(x) &= x - 1
\end{align}
$$

Equate them $y_{1}(x) = y_{2}(x)$ and solve for $x$.

You are looking for the roots of
$$
y(x) = x^{2}+6x-10
$$
They are 
$$
x_{\pm} = -3 \pm \sqrt{19} \approx \left(-7.3589, 1.3589 \right)
$$

[image: parabola]